# Dynamic Drive context menu script breaks jQuery

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I'm using [Dynamic Drive's jQuery Context Menu script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/contextmenu.htm) and I can get the context menus to work, but once I add those scripts, it breaks all of the other jQuery that was previously working...

I'm assuming it might have something to do with the script using `jQuery` and `.noConflict()` instead of `$`, but i'm no expert.

The reason I'm wanting to stick with this script is because of how it handles collisions and menu positions. This is the only one I've found so far that positions the context menu above the cursor if there isn't enough room below the cursor. Every other scripts' menus just get cut off from the document.

I would post all of my jQuery that breaks with the context menu script, but there's nothing fancy about it, so here's just a basic version:

```
$(function(){
    $("#selector").hide();
});
```

If anyone could help fix this script, or recommend a new one that doesn't have the positioning problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line from the dynamic drive portion of the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You only need to include jQuery once for it to handle all scripts that require it.

Modify the script you downloaded from DD and remove this line:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

It should be toward the top of the file. Since you are only including jquery once, it isn't needed. However, I still can't get that to run in jsFiddle, i'm getting an odd error. http://jsfiddle.net/kybp9/

Edit: It now works:
http://jsfiddle.net/kybp9/1/

**UPDATE**
Replace this part of the plugin

```
jQuery.fn.addcontextmenu = function(contextmenuid) {
    var $ = jQuery
    return this.each(function() { //return jQuery obj
        var $target = $(this)
        jquerycontextmenu.init($, $target, $('#' + contextmenuid))
    })
};
```

with this to avoid the `$contextmenu.get(0)` is undefined errors:

```
jQuery.fn.addcontextmenu = function(contextmenuid) {
    var $ = jQuery,
        $contextmenu = $('#' + contextmenuid));
    if (!$contextmenu.length) {
        // no contextmenu found, exit
        return this;
    }
    return this.each(function() { //return jQuery obj
        var $target = $(this)
        jquerycontextmenu.init($, $target, $contextmenu)
    })
};
```

Comment: I'm only including jQuery (what I've been using), jqcontextmenu.js, the CSS, and the javascript chunk. Sorry, I should have specified.

Comment: Hmm.. that works, until I change the selector to something that actually exists on my page. `a.mylinks` doesn't exist on my page, so the rest of the jQuery works. As soon as I change that to `#pins a` (which does exist), the jQuery stops working, and the context menus work.

Comment: Are any javascript errors happening? What are your other jquery scripts that stop working?

Comment: Make sure you are using the plugin properly. The argument should be an id that exists on the page. `$('a.mylinks').addcontextmenu('contextmenu11')` Notice that it also doesn't use a `#` like other jquery methods.

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion with replacing the code. It doesn't cause the rest of the jQuery to break, but the context menus don't work.  I appreciate your help by the way.

Comment: Right, you aren't referencing an element that exists for the context menu.